# The first request to remove an entity are more longer than next

Tags: wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core in WPF application with a SQLite database.

When I try to remove an entity, the first time is more longer than the nexts. The first request can take more than few seconds while the next are almost instant.

There is a pragma or an other fix to do to the database or Entity Framework Core to improve the execution's time of the first request ?

Comment: Probably due to caching... If this is a stored procedure being called, then look at it using sql profiler and see if there is a missing index or something that can make the query run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known "issue", first requests are slow because it's when EF Core configures table mappings.

The bigger your context is the slower the first request will be.

The most important thing you can do here is split you DbContext in multiple parts (DDD approach).

A quick win is to use the fluent API overloads that accepts a string instead of a lambda function as in the following :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(nameof(User.Name));
```

Instead of :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(o => o.Name);
```

If you have hundreds of tables and properties this should improve things.

EF Core team is aware of this, and we will probably get some kind of pre-compiled or "cached" models in future releases, you can track this [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16496) or [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1906).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have seen that more bigger is the database more the first request is longer (for example to remove an entity). I will try your trick to improve that.

Comment: Yep, what I meant by context is DbContext, but you can have multiple DbContexts per database, this enables you to have smaller and more granular DbContexts and substantially reduces time to accomplish first request.